# Return PAIR of all unique possible combinations from single column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

There are two columns Employee_ID and Employee_Name as shown below in a database.

Exmaple table is like below :

```
Employee_ID     Employee_Name
1001              Sam
1002              Jon
1003              Molly
1004              Margot
```

Expected output in SQL:

```
( Sam -> Jon)
( Sam -> Molly )
( Sam -> Margot )
( Jon -> Molly )
( Jon -> Margot )
( Molly -> Margot )
```

Please note : the pair must not repeat itself.
For Example:

```
( Sam -> Molly )
( Molly -> Sam )
```

OR

```
( Sam -> Margot )
( Margot -> Sam )
```

The query tried:

```
SELECT a.emp_name, b.emp_name
FROM emp_info a, emp_info b
where a.emp_name <> b.emp_name;
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

You could self-join the table with an inequality condition on the id, like so:

```
select e1.Employee_Name, e2.Employee_Name
from employee e1
inner join employee e2 on e1.Employee_ID < e2.Employee_ID
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7e930883d7c1cede5f39df34a6857517)**:

```
Employee_Name | Employee_Name
:------------ | :------------
Sam           | Jon          
Sam           | Molly        
Sam           | Margot       
Jon           | Molly        
Jon           | Margot       
Molly         | Margot
```

Comment: Thanks GMB. I am learning sql. Previously I was trying following query, but could not get answer. Apologies I didn't post the query previously in questions.

```

SELECT a.emp_name, b.emp_name
FROM emp_info a, emp_info b
where a.emp_name <> b.emp_name;

```

Comment: @ani2l: the query you were trying would give you duplicate pairs like `Sam, Jon` and `Jon, Sam`. The inequality condition on `id` avoids that. Side note: you should have posted your attempt in your question and explain the problem that you were having with it, that would have probably avoided the downvote it received...

Comment: True, thanks for the suggestion, next surely will put attempt

Comment: @ani2l: while we are at it, another good practice is to only tag with *one* database product. As commented by Dale K, you should not tag both `sql-server` and `mysql`. Just keep one tag out of those two, that corresponds to the database that you are using.